# SDL2 - difference between RGB888 and RGB24

Tags: sdl-2

As best I understand, both the `RGB888` and `RGB24` formats put their red components first, followed by green and then blue, and both formats take a total of 24 bits per pixel (because 8+8+8 = 24). Given this information both identifiers appear to describe the exact same format but I can verify that some of my code works with one of the two formats but not the other. What's the difference between the two that makes them incompatible?

Comment: I am just guessing. But it is common for systems to use 32 bits to hold RGB24, with 8 bits being completely wasted. This is because it is often easier/faster to the addressing.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

They are different. If you look at `SDL2/SDL_pixels.h` you'll find:

```
SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGB24 =
    SDL_DEFINE_PIXELFORMAT(SDL_PIXELTYPE_ARRAYU8, SDL_ARRAYORDER_RGB, 0,
                           24, 3)

SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGB888 =
    SDL_DEFINE_PIXELFORMAT(SDL_PIXELTYPE_PACKED32, SDL_PACKEDORDER_XRGB,
                           SDL_PACKEDLAYOUT_8888, 24, 4)

SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBX8888 =
    SDL_DEFINE_PIXELFORMAT(SDL_PIXELTYPE_PACKED32, SDL_PACKEDORDER_RGBX,
                           SDL_PACKEDLAYOUT_8888, 24, 4)
```

So RGB24 is a tightly packed three byte format (`RRGGBB`), while `RGB888` is a four byte format with the first byte going ignored (`XXRRGGBB`). So the format is just confusingly named and `XRGB8888` would be a more appropriate name.

Don't know why they called it `RGB888` instead of `XRGB8888`, but they leave the leading `X` away on other formats as well.

Answer (score -3):

From my understanding RGB24 formats it's data in bit triplets, whereas RGB888 simply concatenates the respective byte for each channel.

RGB24:

```
RGBRGBRG BRGBRGBR GBRGBRGB
```

RGB888:

```
RRRRRRRR GGGGGGGG BBBBBBBB
```

I highly doubt RGB24 serves a functional or technical benefit, as it would be easier to just load the byte into memory like you would do with RGB888.  But I'm not sure.